# Wann kann man Konjunktiv I im Sinn von Konjunktiv II benutzen?

Tags: grammar, usage, subjunctive

Aus [Außenminister Steinmeiers Rede](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Infoservice/Presse/Reden/2014/141115_Rede_BM_anl%C3%A4sslich_Verleihung_Lead_Awards.html):

> Diese Distanz ist besser gewahrt, wenn auch Journalisten sich vor der Versuchung schützen, Politiker zu sein, wenn sie darauf verzichten, mit einer geschickten Kampagne mal ins Räderwerk der Demokratie zu greifen, und wenn sie auch davon absehen, andere, wirkliche Politiker so zu attackieren, **als seien sie Konkurrenten**. Das sind sie nicht. Politiker sind keine Journalisten, und Journalisten keine Politiker.

Es scheint hier ein klassischer Fall, den Konjunktiv II zu benutzen:

> ..., als wären sie Konkurrenten.

Trotzdem wird der Konjunktiv I benutzt. Warum? In welchen Situationen ist das angemessen?

Comment: [Belles Lettres](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/konjunktiv.php#vergleich) hat sich hierüber auch ausgelassen. Persönlich empfinde ich die Verwendung des Konjunktivs I hier auch als falsch.

Comment: Belles Lettres stellt am Anfang Behauptungen auf und danach wird alles für falsch erklärt oder passend geklopft, was die Behauptungen in Frage stellen könnte (sehr wissenschaftlich). Wenn man statt dessen einfach mal Recherche betreibt, sieht man schnell, dass als + Konjunktiv I üblich ist.

Comment: @Veredomon: Während die Absolutheit der Behauptungen von Belles Lettres in der Tat ein Problem sind, treffen sie auf den Punkt, warum ich den Konjunktiv I in diesen Fällen als falsch empfinde. Ich bestreite nicht, dass diese Verwendung (in sprachbewussten Kreisen) verbreitet ist und man sie mit einer gewissen Berechtigung als regulär ansehen könne, aber dann würden diese Fälle einen sehr beschränkten Sonderfall bilden, da sie von der sonstigen Verwendung der Konjunktive abweichen – und eben das stößt mir auf.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Was falsch ist, ist Indikativ, der so gut wie nicht zu finden ist. Dass da oft noch Konjunktiv I steht, ist sehr schön, weil man daran zeigen kann, dass Konjunktiv I einmal wie Konjunktiv II verwendet werden konnte. Das sollte man pflegen und abkanzeln, wie es Belles Lettres tut. Aber er kann ja gerne Indikativ verwenden, wenn er es denn möchte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laut *Duden – Die Grammatik* stehen modale Relativsätze, welche im Allgemeinen durch *als, als ob, als wenn* oder *wie wenn* eingeleitet werden, im Konjunktiv II. Weiter heißt es dort allerdings, dass tatsächlich in knapp einem Drittel der Fälle ohne erkennbaren Bedeutungsunterschied der Konjunktiv I verwendet wird. (Der Indikativ wird nur vereinzelt eingesetzt.)

Answer (score 4):

Ich halte das für ein lebendes Relikt aus der Zeit des Mittelhochdeutschen, als Konjunktiv Präsens (I) und Konjunktiv Präteritum (II) sich vor allem durch die zeitliche Verwendung unterschieden.

Für "sein" gibt es sogar meiner Erinnerung nach einen leichten Überhang von Konjunktiv I nach "als".

Google N-Gram:

[als sei gegen als wäre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=als+sei%2Cals+w%C3%A4re&year_start=1600&year_end=2014&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cals%20sei%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cals%20w%C3%A4re%3B%2Cc0)

"als sei" kommt im Laufe des 19. Jahrhunderts hoch und liegt im Laufe des 20. Jahrhunderts leicht vor "als wäre".

[als könne gegen als könnte](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=als+k%C3%B6nne%2Cals+k%C3%B6nnte&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cals%20k%C3%B6nne%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cals%20k%C3%B6nnte%3B%2Cc0)

Entwickelt sich ziemlich parallel, hat aber einen stärkeren Überhang im 19. Jahrhundert.

[als habe gegen als hätte](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=als+habe%2Cals+h%C3%A4tte&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cals%20habe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cals%20h%C3%A4tte%3B%2Cc0)

Läuft sehr parallel und geht erst in der jüngeren Vergangenheit zu Gunsten von "als hätte" auseinander.

[als schlafe gegen als schliefe](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=als+schlafe%2Cals+schliefe&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cals%20schlafe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cals%20schliefe%3B%2Cc0)

Durchgehende Dominanz von als schliefe.

Für mich ist das ein schönes Sprachfossil und bestens geeignet, um zu zeigen, dass der Konjunktiv Präteritum auch mal eine andere Funktion hatte als nur die Wiedergabe eines Referats. Falsch ist es definitiv nicht.

**Zu Quellen** (Bezieht sich auf die erste Frage):

[Karoline Jaeck - Konjunktiv I: Synchron und Diachron](http://www.amazon.de/Konjunktiv-Synchron-diachron-Karoline-J%C3%A4ckh/dp/3860574701/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1417475772&sr=8-1&keywords=jaeckh+konjunktiv)

Ist aus meiner Sicht eine streckenweise unnötig komplizierte Diss, hat aber eine lange Reihe an Sprachbelegen, die sehr interessant sind und an denen man die Entwicklung – eher gesagt, den Untergang – des Konjunktivs I nachvollziehen kann.
Für den Konjunktiv II habe ich nichts Vergleichbares.

Zur Entstehung: Der Konjunktiv ist aus dem indoeuropäischen Optativ entstanden, siehe Sprachgeschichte, Besch, S. 2511. Da findet man sicher mehr über die Geschichte des Konjunktivs (ich brauchte nur den Beleg für Optativ -> Konjunktiv)

Comment: Rein aus Interesse (ich zweifle deine Antwort nicht an): Kennst du eine gute Quelle, wo man die historische Entstehung/Entwicklungs des Konjunktivs und der Verwendung von Konj. I und II nachlesen kann?

Comment: Sehr interessante Antwort! Aber sind N Grams nicht irreführend? Nach meinem Sprachgefühl bedeutet „als schliefe“, daß nicht geschlafen wird. „Als schlafe“ dagegen empfinde ich als neutral. Somit kann man aus ngrams ohne Kontext nichts ableiten! Halten Sie es anders? Mir ist allerdings  auch schon aufgefallen, daß beispielsweise Stephan Zweig an etlichen Stellen nach ‚als’ Konjunktiv I einsetzt, wo ich Konjunktiv II gewählt hätte. Speziell mit „sein“. Im Prinzip sehe auch ich eine der von Ihnen beschriebenen ähnliche  Entwicklung.